# Why is an action in a nested .then() happening before it should be receiving a resolved promise?

Tags: node.js, sharp

```
async function ImageResize(list){

    var toPath = path.join(dir, destdir);

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var fromPath = path.join(dir, list[i]);

        let files = await fs.readdir(fromPath);

        for (const element of files) {

            var readPath = path.join(fromPath, element);

            let fileStats = await fs.stat(readPath);
            let buffer = await fs.readFile(readPath);
    
            var bitmap = bmp.decode(buffer, true);
    
            var writePath = path.join(toPath, element);
            
            var preOpTime = Date.now();
    
            sharp(bitmap.data, { raw: {
                width: bitmap.width,
                height: bitmap.height,
                channels: 4
            }})
            .resize(2552, 2046)
            .webp({lossless: false})
            .toFile(writePath, (err, info) => {
                console.log(info);

                z += 1

                console.log(z)
    
                if (err != null){
                    throw err;
                }
    
                else {
                    LogBuilder(fileStats, info, (Date.now() - preOpTime));
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I have the above function in a program. It is handed an array of folder names, steps through them, and resizes the images for me before saving them elsewhere. I'm using Sharp to accomplish this. The function promise is supposed to resolve after sharp has saved the new picture with the .toFile method.

```
ListBuilder()
.then((list) => {
    ImageResize(list)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Image Resize Complete!");
        console.log("Total Pre Compression Memory Size : " + totalPreShrinkSize);
        console.log("Total Post Compresion Memory Size : " + totalPostShrinkSize);
        console.log("Total Elapsed Time : " + elapsedTime);
    })
})
```

Output Example:

```
40
{
  format: 'webp',
  width: 2552,
  height: 2046,
  channels: 4,
  premultiplied: true,
  size: 278224
}
41
Image Resize Complete!
Total Pre Compression Memory Size : 504333862
Total Post Compresion Memory Size : 9584044
Total Elapsed Time : 5951
{
  format: 'webp',
  width: 2552,
  height: 2046,
  channels: 4,
  premultiplied: true,
  size: 278544
}
42
{
  format: 'webp',
  width: 2552,
  height: 2046,
  channels: 4,
  premultiplied: true,
  size: 280038
}
43
{
  format: 'webp',
  width: 2552,
  height: 2046,
  channels: 4,
  premultiplied: true,
  size: 280014
}
44
{
  format: 'webp',
  width: 2552,
  height: 2046,
  channels: 4,
  premultiplied: true,
  size: 285260
}
45
```

EDIT: I've rewritten the function to use await statements. I am now incrementing through it 40+ times, before executing the .then appended to the async function. .then should only execute after it has received a resolved promise. Would this not resolve after the total completion of the ImageResize()? How else would I ensure the entire function is complete before outputting log data?

Comment: I would suggest rewriting your code to use `async/await`, this is like callback hell but with promises. Also, where are `reject` and `resolve` coming from?

Comment: Hey @robertklep, I took your suggestion and rewrote the function to use awaits. However, I'm now incrementing through it 40+ times, stepping out to log data (which shouldn't happen until completion) then continuing. What am I missing?

Comment: From what I can see, if you don't pass a callback to `sharp(…).toFile(…)`, it will return a promise that you can `await` as well.

Comment: The .toFile() portion is executing when I want it to. It simply calls another function that's incrementing up my "log" values. My current problem is it iterating through the function 40+ times before resolving the promise of the ImageResize function, executing a .then() chunk of code, and then continuing in ImageResize.

Comment: _"My current problem is it iterating through the function 40+ times"_. Because you're not using `await` on `sharp().toFile()`.

Comment: I must not be understanding something @robertklep. The sharp().toFile() promise / callback portion is working correctly. It is executing a callback to another function adding some values together, then continuing to run. This is working 40 times out of 45. It then for some reason executes a .then() appended to the entire ImageResize() function (which shouldn't execute until the entire function completes and default resolves its promise), and then continuing for the final 5 out of 45.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by mixing promises and callbacks:

```
sharp(bitmap.data, { raw: {
    width: bitmap.width,
    height: bitmap.height,
    channels: 4
}})
.resize(2552, 2046)
.webp({lossless: false})
.toFile(writePath, (err, info) => {
    console.log(info);

    z += 1

    console.log(z)

    if (err != null){
        throw err;
    }

    else {
        LogBuilder(fileStats, info, (Date.now() - preOpTime));
    }
})
```

This code will not wait for `sharp().toFile()` to complete, so you're basically starting `list.length` parallel image manipulations. It will also cause the call to `ImageResize` to return before those manipulations are completed.

Instead, use promises:

```
const info = await sharp(bitmap.data, { raw: {
    width: bitmap.width,
    height: bitmap.height,
    channels: 4
}})
.resize(2552, 2046)
.webp({lossless: false})
.toFile(writePath);

console.log(info);
z += 1
console.log(z)
LogBuilder(fileStats, info, (Date.now() - preOpTime));
```

Comment: My original problem was indeed causing ImageResize to return before my image manipulations were complete. My current issue is it's completing 42 manipulations, returning a "complete" promise, and then finishing the final 3 manipulations. Changing from callback to promise on .toFile() didn't seem to fix the issue for me.

Comment: Before it was completing 40 manipulations, now 42. This is a tell-tale sign of not waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete. If `LogBuilder()` is doing something asynchronous, you'd have to `await` that as well (provided that it's either marked as `async` _or_ that it explicitly returns a promise).

Comment: I have played with changing the for loops to 'await Promise.all(**.map(async(*) =>{}' This has made it work the way I initially wanted. Though It is now much slower in the operation. I appreciate the help.